# Chrome Extension to change Style Elements, insertCSS not working. is there a better option?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension

I have some simple element styles I'd like to change with a Chrome Extension.

I just want to change the width value from 10em to 20em, for example. I would also like to be able to undo the change and or be able to enter the value from the popup.

```
#mw-panel {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 10em;
    left: 0;
}
```

I removed the styles.css from the manifest.json file and I also added the css file to the manifest.json file in the hopes of being able to enable/disable the CSS with the popup buttons.

```
   "web_accessible_resources": [
    {
    "resources": ["styles.css"],
    "matches": ["https://en.wikipedia.org/*"]
    }
    ]
```

I have a working extension with popup HTML and js files. I tried using insertCSS in the content.js but read that it will not work from there but should from a popup or background js file. I was hoping to also use the removeCSS function.

I also read that with some of the ways you can load a CSS file, the !important modifier will not work. So this may all be for not.

I currently can't get passed this error after clicking the popup button:
*Error handling response: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'insertCSS')*

```
    $('.format').click(function() {
    chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function (tabs){
    var activeTab = tabs[0];
            chrome.scripting.insertCSS({
                target: { tabId: activeTab.id },
                file: ["styles.css"]
            });
    /*chrome.tabs.sendMessage(activeTab.id, {"buttonclicked": "wider"});*/
   });
```

Comment: If you want to try a non-extension approach: https://mcdlr.com/css-inject/.

Comment: 1) Content scripts can't use chrome.scripting or chrome.tabs. 2) `tabId: activeTab` should be `tabId: activeTab.id`, 3) No need for web_accessible_resources, 4) Note that the popup is a separate window so it has its own separate devtools: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu.

Comment: Thanks. 1) That is why I moved it to the popup.js file, sorry not sure what the issue is. Never done this before. 2) Changed to `tabId: activeTab.id`, 3) Removed 4) That is how I found the error I'm stuck on. It's still not working or are you saying the popup.js counts as a content script and that is why I get the error?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to set `file` to `files`

```
chrome.scripting.insertCSS({
   target: { tabId: activeTab.id },
   files: ["styles.css"]
});
```